# Pascal. Вложить onclick в другой onclick

Tags: pascal

Программа вычисляет результат функции.
На форме есть выпадающее меню с действием "Вычислить" и кнопка "Вычислить". У меня есть событие на простую кнопку.  Можно ли чтобы при нажатии на элемент "Вычислить" из списка делалось тоже самое что и на кнопке без копирования всего кода onclick кнопки в onclick элемента меню?

Comment: procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
... end;

procedure TForm1.N2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
?
end;

Comment: Используйте кнопку "править" и добавьте это в вопрос, плиз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
N2.OnClick := Button1Click; //
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно написать процедуру, которая будет вызываться и при нажатии кнопки и элемента меню.

```
 procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
 begin
    CalculateProc;
 end;

 procedure N1Click(Sender: TObject); 
 begin
    CalculateProc;
 end;
```

А вообще для случая, когда разные элементы управления делают одно и то же, лучше сделать `action` и привязать его к ним.

Comment: Это шаг в верном направлении - отделение интерфейса от модели.